# How to deduce that two random variables are equivalent?

Tags: probability, bernoulli-distribution

For example,
\begin{equation}
Y_1=
\begin{cases}
x & \text{with prob. } p\\
1-x & \text{with prob. } 1-p
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
Y_2=\begin{cases}
x & \text{with prob. } 2p-1\\
0 & \text{with prob. } 1-p\\
1 & \text{with prob. } 1-p
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $x\in\{0,1\}$ and $p\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$.

Comment: They're not equations, really, and they're not equivalent. They are two different specifications of random variables (both named $y$) with equal expected values (that is, averages).

Comment: I would use a capital letter $Y$ to emphasize that it is random, whereas $x$ is (I assume) a nonrandom binary value. To see that both specifications for $Y$ result in the same type of Bernoulli random variable, you might consider first the case $x=0$, then the case $x=1$.

Comment: Sorry, I read $x \in \{0, 1\}$ as $x \in [0, 1]$ by mistake. Yes, if $x$ is either $0$ or $1$, you should case-wise assign it either value, collect terms, and determine that they yield the same Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong explanation, maybe I should use the term "distribution"? @BrianTung

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the suggestion, I will modify my notation. @Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can look at conditional distributions $P(Y_i|x)$.

$Y_1$ is already in this form:
\begin{align}
P(Y_1=x)&=p\\
P(Y_1=1-x)&=1-p\\
\end{align}

Thus we focus on $Y_2$. It is easy to see that $P(Y_2=x)$ is equivalent to the cases
\begin{align}
P(Y_2=0 \wedge x=0)&=\underbrace{(2p-1)}_{Y_2=x}+\underbrace{(1-p)}_{Y_2=0\text{ regardless of }x}=p\\
P(Y_2=1 \wedge x=1)&=\underbrace{(2p-1)}_{Y_2=x}+\underbrace{(1-p)}_{Y_2=1\text{ regardless of }x}=p\\
\end{align}
and thus $P(Y_2=x)=p$.

Similarly, for $P(Y_2=1-x)$ we have two cases:
\begin{align}
P(Y_2=0 \wedge x=1)&=\underbrace{(1-p)}_{Y_2=0\text{ regardless of }x}=1-p\\
P(Y_2=1 \wedge x=0)&=\underbrace{(1-p)}_{Y_2=1\text{ regardless of }x}=1-p
\end{align}
and so $P(Y_2=1-x)=1-p$.

Therefore, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ follow the same distribution.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: By the way, there's a small typo in the third to last line, which should be $x=0$.

Comment: Corrected, thanks for noticing!